# Просьба помочь, не могу разобраться

Tags: java

Допишите конструктор в класс Time, который принимает время в секундах.

```
public class Time {
    int hour, min, sec;
    // YOUR CODE will be placed HERE
    // ...  
    public String toString() {
        return hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }   
}
```

так чтобы, например, фрагмент кода

```
Time time = new Time(3661);
System.out.println(time);
```

Вывел 1:1:1 (один час, одна минута, одна секунда)

Comment: Эээ.... И в чем проблема?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как же это сделать

Comment: сделать что именно? Вы секунды в минуты затрудняетесь перевести или конструктор не знаете, как пишется?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что именно требуется в задании

Comment: Тогда следует перечитать учебник, чтобы начать понимать.

Answer (score 0):

Так сойдёт?

```
public class Time {

        int hours, minutes, seconds;

        public Time(int totalSecs) {
            this.hours = totalSecs / 3600;
            this.minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;
            this.seconds = totalSecs % 60;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Откуда он знает, сойдет или нет, если он даже не понимает о чем вопрос...

Comment: Начнём с того, что не стоит давать ответы людям, которые просят все сделать за них, так как Вы их этим поощряете

Comment: @Kir_Antipov про ответы, есть целая [дискуссия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9743/179763) про это на мете

Comment: @tym32167: знаю. И Вы видите, какого мнения придерживаюсь я ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я тоже не испытываю много радости от этого, но что поделать

Comment: @tym32167: whooops хД Спасибо, что обратили мое внимание

Comment: Насчёт поощрения бездействия - прислушаюсь.

Comment: @Leonis: по поводу этого - это моя личная позиция, к которой я не призываю, но все же считаю, что здравое зерно в ней есть. Однако предупреждаю: у нас здесь есть люди, которые возвели данную позицию в абсолют, так что минусуют не только сам вопрос, заданный таким вот лодырем, но и все ответы на таковой, чтобы отбить желание у людей поощрять подобное. Так что Вы рисковали нарваться на минусы при вполне себе правильном ответе ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯